# Troubles allocating with new[] under g++

Tags: c++, g++, new-operator

This is my first experience with g++, so I might be missing something obvious. I installed MinGW (6.3.0) and am compiling following snippet on Windows.
Compiling with no flags (that is required by the task) so just "g++ my_main.cpp"

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int s = 10;
    int *a = new int[s];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles, but upon running displays error window with close translation "Unable to find entry point in __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length not found in DLL libstdc++-6.dll". When I replace new int[s] with new int[10] it compiles and runs with no problems. What is the catch?

EDIT: mingw.org seems to be an outdated project, installed MinGW-w64, all works as a charm.

Comment: ISO C++ doesn't not allow to specify array size from a variable. Use a vector instead.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I don't believe that this code is using variable-length arrays, which are indeed not standard C++. This seems like a more straightforward case of using the `new[]` operator.

Comment: Potentially related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360014/the-procedure-entry-point-znst8-detail15-list-node-base7-m-hookeps0-could-not

Comment: @Chelmy88 You need to distinguish global arrays and those with local storage duration from dynamically allocated ones. The former indeed do require compile time constant size (otherwise it would be the famous VLA), the latter *not*. The code in the question is totally legal.

Comment: Hi all, indeed you are correct I read the code a bit too fast. Sorry

Comment: Side note: Linux g++ accepts without any issue.

Comment: Looks like you mixed runtime/dll platform architectures, you are building 32 or 64 bit and mixing with improper 64 or 32 bit dll.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I cannot use a vector, I cannot specify any flags by the conditions of the task, so I cant link standard library

Comment: @S.M. I have a 64 bit system, and the MinGW specifically mention on their site that it only has 32 version, which however works on any 64 bit system. If you imply that I linked something myself that is not the case, I just use it out of the box.

Comment: What mingw distribution did you use? These days there seem to be dozens of them.

Comment: This seems related: [program linking fails when using custom built gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230777/program-linking-fails-when-using-custom-built-gcc)

Comment: You might try: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64 (link to project there).

Comment: @user4581301 Downloaded from http://www.mingw.org/, this is official, isn't it?

Comment: @ProblemSir mingw.org is old , mingw-w64 is a fork that is under active development

Comment: @M.M and Aconcagua thanks! mingw-w64 compiles and runs with no problem :)

Comment: @ProblemSir OK; as discussed on the question I linked you may well have old mingw version DLLs on your system path, I would recommend tracking them down and removing them to avoid any similar problems in future